# How to derive the formal solution of Heisenberg's equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, commutator, time-evolution

In the book Introductory to Quantum Optics https://ostad.hormozgan.ac.ir/ostad/UploadedFiles/386042/386042-1758823246346514.pdf, we have that for an arbitrary operator $\hat{O}$ having no explicit time dependence, Heisenberg's equation reads
\begin{align}
\frac{d \hat{O}}{d t} =\frac{i}{\hbar}[\hat{H},\hat{O}]. \tag{2.19}
\end{align}
Then Eq.(2.23) provides the formal solution to Eq. (2.19) in the form
\begin{align}
\hat{O}(t) = e^{i \hat{H}t/\hbar} \hat{O}(0) e^{-i \hat{H}t/\hbar}. \tag{2.23}
\end{align}
My question is how to obtain Equation (2.23).

Comment: I think that the easiest way is to substitute $O(t)$ as written in (2.23) into the Heisenberg equation and check that it is satisfied.

Comment: @Matteo This is an answer.

Comment: "My question is how to obtain Equation (2.23)." You seem to have already obtained it, since there it is! If you are asking how to justify it, you can plug it into your Eq. 2.19 to show that it is a solution. If you are asking for additional justification, consider that in the Schrodinger picture, for a Hamiltonian $\hat H$ without explicit time dependence, we have $|\Psi(t)> = e^{-iHt/\hbar}|\Psi(0)>$. And then consider what kind of time dependence the operators must have in the Heisenberg picture such that $<\Psi(t)|\hat O_S|\Psi(t)> = <\Psi(0)|O_H(t)|\Psi(0)>$.

Answer (score 2):

Albert Messiah's Quantum Mechanics book has a good description of this (CH .VIII, Sec. 10 through CH. VIII, Sec. 19).

Firstly, the Heisenberg 'picture' of the Schrodinger equation (your 2.19) is obtained by applying a unitary transformation to the Schrodinger equation. Specifically it presents operators as *time-dependent* and states as being *time-independent*. Therefore the unitary operator needs to be a function of time: more specifically needs to propagate the operator $\hat{O}_o$ in time.Your eqn. 2.23 is precisely a unitary transformation of the operator $\hat{O}(t)$ (where a unitary operator obeys the property $\hat{U}\hat{U}^\dagger = \hat{1}$). So we're asking how do we get the form of the unitary operator as being the time-dependent complex exponential?

Actually, $\hat{U}$ obeys the time-dependent Schrodinger equation$^\ddagger$, $i\hbar \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\hat{U}(t) = \hat{H}\hat{U}(t)$, for which the solution is $\exp{\frac{-i\hat{H}t}{\hbar}}$. This shoots the operator $\hat{O}$ forward in time, it is unitary, and therefore $\hat{U} \hat{O}_o \hat{U}^\dagger$ is a solution.

---

$^\ddagger$ We can show this. Assume I want to make a state $|t_0\rangle$ 'move forward' in time. Let's assume there is an operator $\hat{U}(t, t_0)$ which does that: $\hat{U}(t, t_0)|t_0\rangle = |t\rangle$. Moving from $t_0 \to t_2$ should be equivalent to successive moves $t_0 \to t_1$, $t_1 \to t_2$. That is equivalent to $$|t_2\rangle = \hat{U}(t_2, t_1)\hat{U}(t_1, t_0)|t_0\rangle.$$ Consider then the infinitesimal transformation in time: $|t + dt\rangle = \hat{U}(t+dt, t) |t_0\rangle$. Consider too that $\lim_{dt \to 0}\hat{U}(t+dt, t) = \hat{1}$ since if we don't propagate a ket in time, it is equivalent to acting with the identity operator: hence, infintesimal translations in time can be seen as first-order expansion (in $dt$) of the time-generation operator: $$1 - iX dt,$$ where the $i$ is included to make (Hermitian) conjugation easier and from an analogy of classical mechanics where the Hamiltonian is the generator of time-translation, $X = \frac{\hat{H}}{\hbar}$ (you need $\hbar^{-1}$ since the expansion has a factor of $dt$, and we need this term to be dimensionless).

So: $$\hat{U}(t + dt) = \hat{1} - i\frac{\hat{H}}{\hbar}dt.$$ Now, this applies to an infinitesimal translation at any time, so let's apply the composition principle and come up with an expression for the finite operator $\hat{U}(t, t_0)$ (I'm not going to write the ket that its acting on, to save typing):
\begin{align}
\hat{U}(t + dt, t_0) &= \hat{U}(t+dt, t)\hat{U}(t, t_0)\\
& =(1 - i\frac{\hat{H}}{\hbar}dt) \hat{U}(t, t_0)\\
\Rightarrow \frac{\hat{U}(t+dt, t) - \hat{U}(t, t_0)}{dt} &= -\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat{H}\hat{U}(t, t_0),
\end{align}

where, notice, the left-hand side of this equation is just the differential operator in finite difference form, so we get: $$i\hbar\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\hat{U}(t, t_0) = \hat{H} \hat{U}(t, t_0).$$

Answer (score 0):

> Heisenberg's equation reads
> \begin{align}
> \frac{d \hat{O}}{d t} =\frac{i}{\hbar}[\hat{H},\hat{O}]. \tag{2.19}
> \end{align}
> Then Eq.(2.23) provides the formal solution to Eq. (2.19) in the form
> \begin{align}
> \hat{O}(t) = e^{i \hat{H}t/\hbar} \hat{O}(0) e^{-i \hat{H}t/\hbar}. \tag{2.23}
> \end{align}
> My question is how to obtain Equation (2.23).

In the so-called "Schrodinger picture," it is the state that evolves with time:
$$
|\Psi(t)\rangle = e^{-iHt/\hbar}|\Psi(0)\rangle
$$
N.b., the above equation only holds when there is no *explicit* time dependence in the Hamiltonian operator.

This means that the expectation value of an operator is generally time dependent:
$$
\langle\hat O\rangle(t) = \langle\Psi(t)|\hat O(0)|\Psi(t)\rangle \equiv \langle\Psi(t)|\hat O_S|\Psi(t)\rangle\;,
$$
where the subscript "S" just means this is what we usually call the "Schrodinger picture."

This should be the same expectation value regardless of whether we work in the "Schrodinger picture," where time dependence is in the state, or in the "Heisenberg picture," where time dependence is transferred to the operator. So, we re-write the above equation:
$$
\langle\hat O\rangle(t) = \langle\Psi(t)|\hat O(0)|\Psi(t)\rangle = \langle\Psi(0)|e^{i\hat H t/\hbar}\hat O(0)e^{-i\hat H t/\hbar}|\Psi(0)\rangle = 
\langle\Psi(0)|\hat O(t)|\Psi(0)\rangle
$$

In other words, since this holds for any $|\Psi(0)\rangle$ we have:
$$
\hat O(t)=e^{i\hat H t/\hbar}\hat O(0)e^{-i\hat H t/\hbar}
$$